# Qt: stackview push a qml causes crash

Tags: c++, linux, qt, qml

I have an embedded project that uses qml, the scenario is like this: the desktop interface has two buttons, when I click a button, I will push Setting.qml with stackview, at this time the program will crash, when I click another button, I will use stackview to push Mp3.qml, the program runs normally, and the interface jumps in. When the program crashes and the daemon is pulled up, it will not crash when I click push Setting.qml again.
The following is the coredump information I intercepted:

> #0  0x0000007f76d4c2b8 in raise () from /lib/libc.so.6
> #1  0x0000007f76d3a9d4 in abort () from /lib/libc.so.6
> #2     0x0000007f771b71e8 in QMessageLogger::fatal(char const*, ...) const    () from /usr/lib/libQt5Core.so.5
> #3  0x0000007f779c8368 in ?? ()    from /usr/lib/libQt5Qml.so.5
> #4  0x0000007f77a08fd4 in ?? () from    /usr/lib/libQt5Qml.so.5
> #5  0x0000007f779e4dfc in    QQmlObjectCreator::finalize(QQmlInstantiationInterrupt&) () from
> /usr/lib/libQt5Qml.so.5
> #6  0x0000007f7799ba64 in ?? () from    /usr/lib/libQt5Qml.so.5
> #7  0x0000007f7799be9c in    QQmlEnginePrivate::incubate(QQmlIncubator&, QQmlContextData*) () from
> /usr/lib/libQt5Qml.so.5
> #8  0x0000007f77999974 in    QQmlComponent::create(QQmlIncubator&, QQmlContext*, QQmlContext*) ()    from /usr/lib/libQt5Qml.so.5
> #9  0x0000007f50665810 in ?? () from    /usr/lib/libQt5QuickTemplates2.so.5
> #10 0x0000007f50666d14 in    QQuickStackView::push(QQmlV4Function*) ()    from    /usr/lib/libQt5QuickTemplates2.so.5
> #11 0x0000007f50682518 in ??    () from /usr/lib/libQt5QuickTemplates2.so.5
> #12 0x0000007f50682950    in QQuickStackView::qt_metacall(QMetaObject::Call, int, void**) ()
> from /usr/lib/libQt5QuickTemplates2.so.5
> #13 0x0000007f77988008 in    QQmlVMEMetaObject::metaCall(QObject*, QMetaObject::Call, int, void**)    () from /usr/lib/libQt5Qml.so.5
> #14 0x0000007f779c2998 in ?? ()    from /usr/lib/libQt5Qml.so.5
> #15 0x0000007f77920654 in    QV4::QObjectMethod::callInternal(QV4::Value const*, QV---Type
>  to continue, or q  to    quit---[41555.331634] dsoc
> = 100000, rsoc = 94912, voltage = 4199,    current_avg = 0, temperature = 2804::Value const*, int) const () from
> /usr/lib/libQt5Qml.so.5
> #16 0x0000007f778e1868 in ?? () from /usr/lib/libQt5Qml.so.5
> #17 0x0000007f77974404 in    QV4::Runtime::method_callProperty(QV4::ExecutionEngine*, QV4::Value*,
> int, QV4::Value*, int) () from /usr/lib/libQt5Qml.so.5
> #18 0x0000007f7792d8ec in ?? () from /usr/lib/libQt5Qml.so.5
> #19 0x0000007f779300b0 in ?? () from /usr/lib/libQt5Qml.so.5
> #20    0x0000007f778f3ed4 in QV4::Function::call(QV4::Value const*,    QV4::Value const*, int, QV4::ExecutionContext const*) () from
> /usr/lib/libQt5Qml.so.5
> #21 0x0000007f779d8510 in    QQmlJavaScriptExpression::evaluate(QV4::CallData*, bool*) () from
> /usr/lib/libQt5Qml.so.5
> #22 0x0000007f7799f108 in    QQmlBoundSignalExpression::evaluate(void**) ()    from
> /usr/lib/libQt5Qml.so.5
> #23 0x0000007f7799f8dc in ?? () from    /usr/lib/libQt5Qml.so.5
> #24 0x0000007f779c8084 in    QQmlNotifier::emitNotify(QQmlNotifierEndpoint*, void**) () from
> /usr/lib/libQt5Qml.so.5
> #25 0x0000007f7798a500 in    QQmlData::signalEmitted(QAbstractDeclarativeData*, QObject*, int,
> void**) () from /usr/lib/libQt5Qml.so.5
> #26 0x0000007f772fd66c in    QMetaObject::activate(QObject*, int, int, void**) ()    from    /usr/lib/libQt5Core.so.5
> #27 0x0000007f5062c4f8 in    QQuickAbstractButtonPrivate::handleRelease(QPointF const&) () from
> /usr/lib/libQt5QuickTemplates2.so.5
> #28 0x0000007f5063f6a4 in    QQuickControl::touchEvent(QTouchEvent*) ()    from    /usr/lib/libQt5QuickTemplates2.so.5    ---Type 
> to continue,    or q  to quit---
> #29 0x0000007f781b78d8 in    QQuickItem::event(QEvent*) ()    from /usr/lib/libQt5Quick.so.5       #30 0x0000007f78563308 in
> QApplicationPrivate::notify_helper(QObject*, QEvent*)    () from
> /usr/lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5
> #31 0x0000007f78567c14 in    QApplication::notify(QObject*, QEvent*) ()    from    /usr/lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5
> #32 0x0000007f772e4c24 in    QCoreApplication::notifyInternal2(QObject*, QEvent*)    () from
> /usr/lib/libQt5Core.so.5
> #33 0x0000007f781c9160 in    QQuickWindowPrivate::deliverMatchingPointsToItem(QQuickItem*,
> QQuickPointerEvent*, bool) () from /usr/lib/libQt5Quick.so.5
> #34    0x0000007f781c9440 in    QQuickWindowPrivate::deliverUpdatedTouchPoints(QQuickPointerTouchEvent*)
> () from /usr/lib/libQt5Quick.so.5
> #35 0x0000007f781c9ed0 in    QQuickWindowPrivate::deliverTouchEvent(QQuickPointerTouchEvent*) ()
> from /usr/lib/libQt5Quick.so.5
> #36 0x0000007f781ca62c in    QQuickWindowPrivate::deliverPointerEvent(QQuickPointerEvent*) () from
> /usr/lib/libQt5Quick.so.5
> #37 0x0000007f781cadac in    QQuickWindowPrivate::handleTouchEvent(QTouchEvent*)    () from
> /usr/lib/libQt5Quick.so.5
> #38 0x0000007f781cb8f8 in    QQuickWindow::event(QEvent*) ()    from /usr/lib/libQt5Quick.so.5       #39 0x0000007f78563308 in
> QApplicationPrivate::notify_helper(QObject*, QEvent*)    () from
> /usr/lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5
> #40 0x0000007f78567c14 in    QApplication::notify(QObject*, QEvent*) ()       ---Type  to continue, or q  to quit---
> from /usr/lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5
> #41 0x0000007f772e4c24 in    QCoreApplication::notifyInternal2(QObject*, QEvent*)    () from
> /usr/lib/libQt5Core.so.5
> #42 0x0000007f77c5eaf0 in    QGuiApplicationPrivate::processTouchEvent(QWindowSystemInterfacePrivate::TouchEvent*)
> () from /usr/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5
> #43 0x0000007f77c5fd20 in    QGuiApplicationPrivate::processWindowSystemEvent(QWindowSystemInterfacePrivate::WindowSystemEvent*)
> () from /usr/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5
> #44 0x0000007f77c4ad58 in    QWindowSystemInterface::sendWindowSystemEvents(QFlagsQEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag)
> () from /usr/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5
> #45 0x0000007f749870a8 in ?? ()    from /usr/lib/libQt5WaylandClient.so.5
> #46 0x0000007f7d4b4a64 in    g_main_context_dispatch ()    from /usr/lib/libglib-2.0.so.0
> #47    0x0000007f7d4b4ce0 in ?? () from /usr/lib/libglib-2.0.so.0
> #48    0x0000007f7d4b4d84 in g_main_context_iteration ()    from    /usr/lib/libglib-2.0.so.0
> #49 0x0000007f77318ea8 in    QEventDispatcherGlib::processEvents(QFlagsQEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag)
> () from /usr/lib/libQt5Core.so.5
> #50 0x0000007f772e0d8c in    QEventLoop::exec(QFlagsQEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag) () from
> /usr/lib/libQt5Core.so.5
> #51 0x0000007f772e55b4 in    QCoreApplication::exec() ()    from /usr/lib/libQt5Core.so.5
> #52    0x0000000000426760 in main ()

Comment: Please share the code which you get error

Comment: This will normally log a message to stderr: #2 0x0000007f771b71e8 in QMessageLogger::fatal(char const*, ...) const () from /usr/lib/libQt5Core.so.5 Can you find it and add it to your question?

Comment: Thank you guys for the comments, I found the problem

Answer (score 1):

Thank you guys for the comments, I found the problem, I noticed a sentence through the log: "QQmlEngine: Illegal attempt to connect to settingWorkCenter(0x7f7c000fe0) that is in a different thread than the QML engine QQmlApplicationEngine(0x7ff2267c38)."
I instantiate the singleton object of settingWorkCenter in another thread, and then register the singleton object to the qml global context through setContextProperty in the main thread. So this error is generated
I'm playing stackflower for the first time and don't know how to upload the code